# nextFeature method for FeatureIterator object in QGIS 3 seemingly not working?

Tags: python, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

How do we get the next feature from a `QgsFeatureIterator` object in QGIS 3? I tried the following with no success:

```
l = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Dissolved')[0]
f = l.getFeatures()
f = f.nextFeature()
```

The error returned by the `.nextFeature` call above is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.2\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: nextFeature(self, f: QgsFeature): not enough arguments
```

What am I doing wrong? How come the iterator `nextFeature` method is asking me for arguments?

Comment: What if you try `next(f)`

Comment: yes that works but whats the point of `nextFeature()` then

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the QGIS Python Cookbook documentation on using [feature iterators](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#iterating-over-vector-layer):

```
l = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Dissolved')[0]
for f in l.getFeatures():
    print ("Feature ID %d: " % f.id())
```

Answer (score 3):

It works actually. But first, you have to create a new `QgsFeature` object (or you can use existing `QgsFeature` object, and pass it to `nextFeature` method.

```py
f = layer.getFeatures()

feat = QgsFeature() # create empty feature in memory
print(feat.isValid())  # False
print(feat.geometry()) # OUT: <QgsGeometry: null> -> geometry of empty feature

f.nextFeature(feat) # assign next feature to feat
print(feat.isValid())  # True
print(feat.geometry()) # OUT: <QgsGeometry: Point (30 30)> -> first feature of layer
```

But I have no idea what the point is, yet.